# Cython throws an error when pass function with void * argument to dict

Tags: python, cython

I have a function with `void *` parameter and I want to store it in the dict.

What I do is:

```
%%cython

cdef void foo(void * bar):
    pass

cdef dict foobar = {'foo': foo}
```

But this code raises an Error: `Cannot convert 'void (void *)' to Python object` Any ways to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a `cdef class` that can wrap this function. Since the `cdef class` is a Python object it can be stored in a dictionary like any other Python object.

```
ctypedef void (*void_func_ptr)(void*)

cdef class VoidFuncWrapper:
    cdef void_func_ptr func
    def __cinit__(self):
       self.func = NULL

    @staticmethod
    cdef VoidFuncWrapper make_from_ptr(void_func_ptr f):
        cdef VoidFuncWrapper out = VoidFuncWrapper()
        out.func = f
        return out
```

Then you can simply do:

```
cdef dict foobar = {'foo': VoidFuncWrapper.make_from_ptr(foo)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that `void*` has no defined converter from a Python object, so a Python wrapper function (that accepts Python objects, converts them, and passes them to the underlying C function) can't be defined, either explicitly with `cpdef` or implicitly by putting the `cdef` function in a Python object (the `dict` in this case).

You could make this work by defining the argument to be something Cython knows how to convert to, e.g.:

```python
cpdef void foo(const char * bar):
    pass

cdef dict foobar = {'foo': foo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP//ycXpKSmKZTlZ6YopOXnayTn5xWXKCRnJBYpaCkkJRZpWnEpAEFBYnExF1cySGlKZnIJSClQUsFWoVodyFS3AgnU/v8PAA)

But that may not work for your scenario if the function needs to accept an arbitrary pointer. If that's the case, you may want to switch to using C++ containers that can hold your function pointer type directly:

```python
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef void foo(void *bar):
    pass

ctypedef void (*f_type)(void *)

cdef unordered_map[string, f_type] foobar

foobar['foo'.encode('ascii')] = foo
```

Comment: I have rapleced `cdef` with `cpdef` but still cann't add the function to the dict. By the way, if I remove all the arguments from the fuction, the code above works fine

Comment: @shadowrander `cpdef` doesn't make any sense because a Python function can accept a `void*` argument

Comment: @IvanMishalkin: I updated my answer. DavidW's answer is probably better for a general purpose solution, but mine is an alternative for specific use cases.